# Script can't import modules, import in shell works fine

Tags: python, import, flask

I recently ran into an issue on my development box. I can run my script line by line fine within the interactive shell, but it fails as soon as it tries to import a module when running the script from the command line.

Specifically, I'm trying to use: `from flask import Flask`

and the error I get is:

```
from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

It was working perfectly fine a couple days ago and I didn't make any changes to the system (that I can recall) so I can't figure out if this is an issue with my python shell or flask.

Things I've checked/tried:

- deleting/reinstalling flask via pip
- confirming C:\Python27\lib\site-packages is in my system path
- clearing and re-adding the directories in my PATH environment variable
- uninstalling/reinstalling Python 2.7.3
- successfully running the following script to test my python shell:

  ```
  from time import gmtime, strftime
  print strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
  ```

I'm open to any new troubleshooting suggestions.

Comment: What is the name of your .py file? What is the complete traceback of the ImportError?

Comment: You probably have a file called `flask.py` in the directory where your script is.

Comment: flaskTest.py
I actually just moved it to a different directory and it worked fine. I think the issue is that the original directory (where it fails) has spaces in it. I don't think I've ever run into that issue before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had originally called the file flask.py and there was an old compiled flask.pyc in the same directory. It worked fine as soon as I moved it to another directory and also when removing the old flask.pyc.

Thanks for the quick comments timc and BrenBarn!

Comment: Happened to me. Renamed file after it was same as a library. The original .pyc file remained and was still conflicting even though the original went away. Had to manually remove the pyc

Answer (score 1):

I made a stupid mistake of naming my script file `nltk.py`. So when I imported `nltk`, it didn't show an error. When I tried calling any functions, it displayed an error.

Make sure that this doesn't happen.